# Create values in Many2one field From many2many wizard (or) TransientModel

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm, odoo, odoo-12

From Following code I Created values in Many2one field From many2many tag field of wizard (or) TransientModel

```
def add_employee_btn(self):
    record = self.env['add.employees'].browse(self._context.get('active_id'))
    for e in self.employee_ids:
        vals={'employee_names':e.name,
              'issue_id': record.id}
        res = self.env['issues.issues'].create(vals)
```

I need Another method Using List append  like this..

```
 def add_employee_btn(self):
     list = []
     record=self.env['add.employees'].browse(self._context.get('active_id'))
     for e in self.employee_ids:
     list.append(({0,0,{'employee_names':e.name,
                    'issue_id': record.id}}))
```

But getting Error in this If some one knows fix it...

Comment: What is the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 def add_employee_btn(self):
     list = []
     record=self.env['add.employees'].browse(self._context.get('active_id'))
     for e in self.employee_ids:
        list.append([0,0,{'employee_names':e.name,
                    'issue_id': record.id}])
```

Please, try this it would may help you to solve error.